# ActiveRecord sort children within parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there a way to pre-sort the children of a parent through ActiveRecord (Rails 3.2.13)?

So if you have a setup like this

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :children

[...]

class Children < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :parent
```

Something *like* this:

`p = Parent.where(:name => 'Diana').includes(:children, :order => 'd_o_b DESC')`

That way when I call `p.children` I am getting an array of objects ordered by birth, and not by their database ID.

Or do I just need to sort my array afterward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Parent` model, change the `has_many` to:

```
has_many :children, :order => 'd_o_b DESC'
```

Then anytime you access the `children` association for a parent record (*e.g.*, `@parent.children`), they'll be in descending order of date of birth.

Comment: `:order` was deprecated in `has_many` in Rails 4, updated answer available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18284635/19794)